# How to use d2i_ECPrivateKey() to load my private key with

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to use `d2i_ECPrivateKey()` to load key from a std::string which contains my private key. My goal is to do the ECDSA signing.

My code snippet.

```cpp
function sign(){
  // random data
  std::string data = "....";

  // 256-bit key in hex
  std::string private_key =
      "ee52189da48a2aeda40e488ce3c711f852ebdd12a21d1c7fd8a5b78a0902fad1";

  const unsigned char *key_cstr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
      const_cast<char *>(private_key.c_str()));

  const unsigned char *data_cstr =
      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(const_cast<char *>(data.c_str()));

  EC_KEY *ec_key = d2i_ECPrivateKey(NULL, &key_cstr, private_key.length());
  if (ec_key == NULL) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "d2i_ECPrivateKey returns NULL";
    return {};
  }

}
```

and  d2i_ECPrivateKey always fails by returning a null object. Anyone can shed some light here? since the openssl documentation is very limited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This approach is incorrect : `d2i_ECPrivateKey` expects key to be binary (not hex string) and DER-encoded. Also this functions call seems to be deprecated, please see https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/d2i_ECPrivateKey.html

P.S. Do you actually use ECDSA with some curve parameters, or Ed25519?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  "P.S. Do you actually use ECDSA with some curve parameters, or Ed25519?"  I'm not sure what you are referring. Actually I'm trying to locate a simple tutorial about how to use OPENSSL to sign data with an existing private key. But cannot find one

Comment: You should first find out which private key you are using: it may represent different curves (like secp256p1, secp256k1, Ed25519) and so on. Depending on that you'll need to pick functions to use, since OpenSSL treats later one (Ed25519) in a different way, see `EVP_PKEY_new_raw_private_key`.

Comment: ... you may find example of OpenSSL ECDSA/EdDSA signing and verification in code here: https://github.com/rnpgp/rnp/blob/master/src/lib/crypto/ecdsa_ossl.cpp 
It's a bit complicated, but would give you an idea which functions to call and when.